# How can I specify maximum number of lines a gtk.TextView can display?

Tags: python, textview, pygtk

I am reading contents from a file and displaying the same in a Textview on a window. I don't want all the lines to be displayed in textview. I want to restrict it to say,first 5 lines only (suppose the file contains 20 lines).

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class Txtview:
 def __init__(self):
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.set_resizable(True)  
    window.set_border_width(0)
    box2 = gtk.VBox(False, 10)
    textview = gtk.TextView()
    textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
    textview.show()
    box2.pack_start(textview)
    infile = open("/newfile.txt", "r")
    if infile:
        string = infile.read()
        infile.close()
        textbuffer.set_text(string)

    window.add(box2)
    window.show_all()

def main():
gtk.main()
return 0       

if __name__ == "__main__":
Txtview()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change the TxtView constructor if block to below form:

```
if infile:
    lines = 5 if len(infile.readlines()) > 5 else len(infile.readlines())
    string = "\n".join(infile.readlines()[:lines])
    textbuffer.set_text(string)
infile.close()
```